# updating fields using proces builder

Tags: process-builder

Trying to make the field of the e-mail change by updating the e-mail address in the contact object. Attached is a screenshot, help me understand what I am doing wrong, because the desired result is not as i imagined [image: the change? is if the contact.email is change then true]

Comment: Well, it would be convenient also if you attach a screenshot of the entry criteria. Could you also explain yourself a little bit better? What email would you like the contact to have? The account's?

Comment: What are the results you are seeing? The less you make us guess the more likely someone will answer